# Cursor issue in absolute div in IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

I have a div containing 2 divs. 
In the first div, there's a span that overflows the parent div (overflow is set to hidden and cursor to pointer). 
The second div is a resize handler with a width of 10px. 
Cursor is set to w-resize

In IE9: When hovering the absolute div, the cursor is correctly shown, except when you're also hovering over the span.

HTML:

```
<div class="div1">
<div class="div2"> 
    <span>Test test test test test test test test test test</span>
</div>
<div class="div3"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.div1{
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}

.div2{
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.div3{
  width: 10px; 
  height: 100%; 
  position: absolute;
  right: -1px; 
  bottom: 0px;     
  cursor: w-resize;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7fpa7vjs/

Thanks for your input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an odd one that I've never seen before.  It seems that this won't work in IE9 without giving the absolute div a `background`.  Obviously you don't want a visible background so I used a transparent pixel image as the background and it now works in IE9.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7fpa7vjs/6/)

Comment: It works! I thought about using background: transparant, but not using a transparant pixel image. Even more elegant solution is background: rgba(0,0,0,0); Thanks

Comment: If you are not concerned about IE8 support then that would definitely be a nicer touch.

Comment: Yeah, the project i'm working on supports IE9+ (fortunately!)

Answer (score 0):

The `CSS3` `cursor` values are added in the 2004 specifications, including `none`, `context-menu`, `cell`, `vertical-text`, `alias`, `copy`, `no-drop`, `not-allowed`, `nesw-resize`, `nwse-resize`, `col-resize`, `row-resize` and `all-scroll`.

Unfortunately Internet Explorer **does not support** the `alias`, `cell`, `copy`, `ew-resize`, `ns-resize`, `nesw-resize`, `nwse-resize` or `context-menu` cursors.

Side note: Also Opera 12.10 does not support `none` or a `URI`.

**Some known issues:** Firefox/Mac, Safari/Mac, Chrome/Mac don't support `PNG` and `JPG` cursors (tested with 48px cursors). 
Internet Explorer only supports cursors in the `CUR` format.

See the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#cursor) and [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) specifications.

Comment: The problem isn't that the cursor isn't displayed correctly, but when hovering the span and the div3, the cursor of the span is shown.
Changing the cursor from w-resize to another one that IE supports doesn't has any impact